# How to apply Kuratowski's theorem here

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[image]

I'm unsure which subgraph to find and which of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ I should compare it to. First this looks like $K_6$. If it was $K_6$, I could simply remove one of the vertices to get $K_5$ and I would be done.
However, there is an extra vertex $I$ in the centre. I thought of removing a vertex say $B$ and then removing edge $IE$ to get $K_5$ with an extra vertex in the middle. Then I'm unsure here because it doesn't seem that this is a subdivision of $K_5$... (the middle point seems like a subdividing vertex for more than one edge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the union of the path $FEDC$ and the graph induced by vertices $A,B,C,I,F$. This subgraph is a subdivision of $K_5$.

Comment: Was this just by intuition or through some general guide? (eg maybe considering the degrees of each vertex)  
Also, im unsure if I'm interpreting it correctly; do you mean by only considering path $FEDC$ (so remove the edges inside the lower half of the shape) and union that with the upper half of the shape?

Comment: @Natash1 Just by intuition. And your interpretation of my answer is correct.

Comment: Ah I see it now! That was nice, thanks

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is joined to $C,E,F$, also $D$ is joined to $C,E,F$, and $B$ is joined to $C$ and $F$, and to $E$ via $I$, so there's also a $K_{3,3}$ there.